# Can this be written more concise and aligned with the Functional Reactive Programming paradigm?

Tags: functional-programming, elm

Trying to learn FRP and Elm. Is the program below "ok" from the perspective of FRP and Elm? What could be improved? The program can be executed here: http://elm-lang.org/try

```
import Random
import Mouse
data Fruit = Apple | Orange | Banana | Melon | Guava
rand = Random.range 0 4 (Mouse.clicks)
fruit n = if | n == 0 -> Apple
             | n == 1 -> Orange
             | n == 2 -> Banana
             | n == 3 -> Melon
             | otherwise -> Guava
fruitText = toForm <~ (asText <~ (fruit <~ rand))
time = lift (inSeconds . fst) (timestamp (fps 40))
scene dy form = collage 300 300 [move (0, 100 * cos dy) form]
main = lift2 scene time fruitText
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Two months late, but I will try to answer nevertheless. ;-)

Since your `rand` already makes sure the numbers will be valid indices for your fruits, you don't have to use so many if cases. The rest looks OK to me, but I made some annotations in the source.

```
import Random
import Mouse
-- Sometimes empty lines can improve readability.

data Fruit = Apple | Orange | Banana | Melon | Guava

-- For module global declarations, it is often helpful to
-- explicitly annotate the types.
fruits : [Fruit]
fruits = [Apple, Orange, Banana, Melon, Guava]

-- especially for functions :)
fruit : Int -> Fruit
fruit n = head <| drop n fruits

rand : Signal Int
rand = Random.range 0 ((length fruits) - 1) Mouse.clicks

-- exercise: Try to figure and annotate the remaining types. ;-)
fruitText = toForm <~ (asText <~ (fruit <~ rand))

time = lift (inSeconds . fst) (timestamp (fps 40))

scene dy form = collage 300 300 [move (0, 100 * cos dy) form]

main = lift2 scene time fruitText
```

btw: share-elm.com is a bit easier for showing elm code to someone than making him copy paste to elm-lang.org/try.
See: http://share-elm.com/sprout/52567327e4b0d6a98b1531c7